# Insert records from two tables that match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE forms 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
    TITLE TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE new_forms 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME TEXT NULL,
    TITLE TEXT NULL
);

INSERT INTO forms VALUES (0, 'test', 'test');
INSERT INTO new_forms VALUES (0, 'new_test', NULL);
```

And I'm using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO forms(id, name, title) 
    SELECT
        1, COALESCE(nf.name, f.name), COALESCE(nf.title, f.title) 
    FROM
        forms f 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        new_forms nf ON nf.id = f.id;

SELECT * FROM forms;
```

The idea is to add both rows that match to the table.

In this example this two new records should be added:

```
1   test        test
1   new_test    test
```

But it's only adding the last one.

I have tried with all the join and none of them worked.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pec6g8z4KCDetj6S7Mdwek/7)

Thanks

Comment: the first row in your expected result already exists in forms table. Do you want to duplicate it?

Comment: @MeyssamToluie Yes

Comment: The query returns 1 row. How come you expect 2 rows to be inserted?

Comment: @jarlh That is the issue. The query should return 2 rows but now sure how.

Comment: Why is your impression it should return 2 rows? (You join 2 tables, having 1 row each. 1 x 1 = 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a join in the query which will give you only 1 row. If you need 2 rows. You have to use `UNION ALL` clause -

```
INSERT INTO forms(id, name, title) 
    SELECT
        1, COALESCE(nf.name, f.name), COALESCE(nf.title, f.title) 
    FROM
        forms f 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        new_forms nf ON nf.id = f.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1, COALESCE(f.name, nf.name), COALESCE(nf.title, f.title) 
    FROM
        forms f 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        new_forms nf ON nf.id = f.id;
```